# Read event viewer entries

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, event-log

I want to read event entries from a certain custom event log at c# program,
And to filter them by their description. 
Is there a way to do it? 
Or a way to get the entries as collection so I will be able to select from that by condition?

Comment: Check the [EventLog class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Checked, there is 'Entries' property, don't know how to read from it by condition.

Comment: Are you talking about the events you would see with the `eventvwr.msc` of Windows, or do you speak about some kind of application driven events?

Comment: The events I would see in the event viewer yes

Comment: Hi Shaked, just saw, that you were around and even started a new question on this issue. Could my answer help you?

Comment: Your answer helped me, now, I'm looking for a way to filter by my needs(as I wrote in the new question)

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for the tips , I will mark you answer as soon as I succeed to get exactly what I need, 'till then I can't fully check if you solution works

Comment: Yes of course. Just placed some hints below your new question ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
       string queryString = string.Format("*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='{0}' and @SystemTime<='{1}']]]",
            DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-10).ToString("s"),
            DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("s"));
        var q = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-User Profile Service/Operational", PathType.LogName, queryString);
        var r = new EventLogReader(q);

        var list = new List<EventRecord>(); 

        EventRecord er = r.ReadEvent();
        while (er != null) {
            list.Add(er);
            er = r.ReadEvent();
        }
```

The filter is `XPath` and `XQuery`. If you want to learn about an events internal structure I found it best to read through the filter definition within `eventvwr`. Look into the `XML`-tab...

Comment: Wow, thanks for heads up about this approach of reading event logs! Thanks to it I was able to decrease time of reading my logs from 35 secs to 4 secs!