# Filter at event viewer by data

Tags: query-string, event-viewer

I want to get event entries by their description (data). 
I know how to get the event entry with a certain description, however I want to get an entry whith a description which contains a string (not equals to it). 
That, I don't know how to do. 
Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

According to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34119006/5089204 you should be able to retrieve EventRecords.

Dealing with these events is a quite complex issue... Each event has its own internal structure. The common properties are bundled in `EventRecord`, but the specific data must be taken from the internal details. Use the `ToXml()` method of an `EventRecord`...

In order to get the right  events you must define an `EventLogQuery`. You must know the Provider's name and specify the filter.

Try the following: Open `eventvwr` and there the Windows-System queue. Right click one event, open the "Details" and choose the "XML-View". Look over different events and you will find, that they are quite differing.

But: You'll find everything you need there: First the "Provider Name" and the "EventId", these two are most important for the `EventLogQuery'.

Now go to the "define a user filter on the current protocoll"-action and type in some values. Then switch to the filter's XML and you'll learn how to define the correct query.

I'm sorry, there is no "easy and general" approach :-)

Comment: I already know the filter at the eventviewer and using it. Now I'm asking for a tip there not at my code

Comment: @Shaked.B This article might help you: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer.aspx. Not all XPath-functions are supported! Regrettfully `contains` isn't. You'd probably load the records as shown and filter them within your application...